# Why isn't ArgumentCaptor matching up properly?

Tags: java, android, mockito

I'm working on an Android app, using AndroidStudio and am hoping someone could tell me why I can't get Mockito to recognize arguments using `argumentCaptor.capture()` or `anyObject()`.

I'm testing `SpanPainter`'s method `applyColor()`:

```
package com.olfybsppa.inglesaventurero.utils;

import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;

public class SpanPainter {
  ForegroundColorSpan color;

  public SpanPainter (ForegroundColorSpan color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
  public SpannableString applyColor(SpannableString span) {
    span.setSpan(color, 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return span;
  }
}
```

My test is:

```
package com.olfybsppa.inglesaventurero.utils;

import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class SpanPainterTest {
  @Test
  public void testAppliesColorPerRange () {
    SpannableString mockSpanString = mock(SpannableString.class);
    ForegroundColorSpan mockForegroundColor = mock(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    SpanPainter painter = new SpanPainter(mockForegroundColor);

    ArgumentCaptor<ForegroundColorSpan> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    painter.applyColor(mockSpanString);

    verify(mockSpanString).setSpan(argumentCaptor.capture(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
    //verify(mockSpanString).setSpan(anyObject(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
  }
}
```

The results are: (I removed the angle brackets)

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
spannableString.setSpan(
    Capturing argument,
    any,
    any,
    any
);
Actual invocation has different arguments:
spannableString.setSpan(
    Mock for ForegroundColorSpan, hashCode: 106298691,
    1,
    2,
    17
);
```

If I remove the commented line and use anyObject(), the results are:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
spannableString.setSpan(any,any,any,any);
Actual invocation has different arguments:
spannableString.setSpan(
    Mock for ForegroundColorSpan, hashCode: 106298691,
    1,
    2,
    17
);
```

It seems to me that at least using `anyObject()` should work, but it doesn't.

### Not referencing my main code anymore, still using Android api objects

Following code gives similar results, 'Arguments are different!Wanted...' 'Capturing argument' vs 'Mock for ForegroundColorSpan, hashCode: xxxx':

```
package com.olfybsppa.inglesaventurero.utils;

import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class DummyTest {
  @Test
  public void testCaptor() {
    SpannableString helper = mock(SpannableString.class);
    ForegroundColorSpan color = mock(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    helper.setSpan(color, 1, 2, 17);
    ArgumentCaptor<ForegroundColorSpan> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    verify(helper).setSpan(captor.capture(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
  }
```

}

### Gradle settings:

Here are my gradle settings:

From overall build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

From app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.olfybsppa.inglesadventurero"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 5
    versionName "5.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  sourceSets {
    main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/start', 'src/main/java/adapters', 'src/main/java/pagers', 'src/main/java/com.olfybsppa.inglesadventurero/pagers']
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
  testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.+'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

### PowerMockito also doesn't work:

I also tried the following, using PowerMockito:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ SpannableString.class, ForegroundColorSpan.class })
public class DummyTest {
  @Test
  public void testCaptor() {
    SpannableString helper = PowerMockito.mock(SpannableString.class);
    ForegroundColorSpan color = PowerMockito.mock(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
```

which continues as before; this also doesn't solve the problem.

### Adding non-android interface:

This test uses `returnDefaultValues = true`, does not use Powermockito, and uses `Object` instead of `ForegroundColorSpan`. Testing to see if subclassing android method and implementing a non-android interface would work.

```
public class SpanPainterTest {
  @Test
  public void testCaptor() {
    SpannableStringSubclass helper = mock(SpannableStringSubclass.class);
    Object color = mock(Object.class);
    helper.setSpan(color, 1, 2, 17);
    ArgumentCaptor<Object> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
    verify(helper).setSpan(anyObject(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
    //verify(helper).setSpan(captor.capture(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface SpannableStringSuper {
  public void setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags);
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class SpannableStringSubclass extends SpannableString implements SpannableStringSuper {
  public SpannableStringSubclass () {
    super("xxx");
  }
}
```

This results in very similar results as first test. 'any' vs 'Mock for Object'. And 'Capturing argument' vs 'Mock for Object'.

Answer (score 6):

I can't reproduce this. Here's the code I used to try to match your scenario:

```
public class DummyTest {
  @Test
  public void testCaptor() {
    SpannableString helper = mock(SpannableString.class);
    ForegroundColorSpan color = mock(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    helper.setSpan(color, 1, 2, 17);
    ArgumentCaptor<ForegroundColorSpan> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    verify(helper).setSpan(captor.capture(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
  }
}
```

This passes just fine for me. I'm using:

- Maven
- Android 4.1.1.4
- JUnit 4.11
- Mockito 1.10.19

Clearly, the fact that mine works and yours doesn't means there's some issue with something outside the class; it could either be a dependency issue or a mock settings configuration issue.

Is it possible you're somehow using two different versions of `ForegroundColorSpan`? Are you setting Mockito settings outside of the tests you've shown me somewhere?

You could try would be swapping them both out **separately** and seeing if they work. For example, try this:

```
public class DummyTest {
  @Test
  public void testCaptor() {
    TestSpannable helper = mock(TestSpannable.class);
    ForegroundColorSpan color = mock(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    helper.setSpan(color, 1, 2, 17);
    ArgumentCaptor<ForegroundColorSpan> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    verify(helper).setSpan(captor.capture(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
  }

  public static interface TestSpannable {
    public void setString(Object what, int start, int end, int flags);
  }
}
```

Then, try something similar using a `SpannableString` type and a different `Object` where you're currently using `ForegroundColorSpan`.

---

I tried running `DummyTest` again, with `RETURNS_DEFAULTS` based on [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062305/1768232) - but doing it inside the test class and not in the build settings, like so:

```
public class DummyTest {
  @Test
  public void testCaptor() {
    SpannableString helper = mock(SpannableString.class, RETURNS_DEFAULTS);
    ForegroundColorSpan color = mock(ForegroundColorSpan.class, RETURNS_DEFAULTS);
    helper.setSpan(color, 1, 2, 17);
    ArgumentCaptor<ForegroundColorSpan> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    verify(helper).setSpan(captor.capture(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyInt());
  }
}
```

This *also* works and doesn't throw your error. Therefore it has something to do with the gradle build setting itself, and not `RETURNS_DEFAULTS` on it's face.

Answer (score 2):

I think that having `unitTest.returnDefaultValues = true` in the project gradle.build file results in default mock objects instead of plain mock Android objects. I think that Mockito does not allow these default mock objects to be used as true mock objects. I think this because method verification on these default mock objects never passed in my tests.

```
defaultObject = mock(SomeAndroidClass.class)
verify(defaultObject).method(argumentCaptor.capture())
```

The above will not pass. The arguments never matched.

I know this answer is not completely substantiated by the documentation, but it is my understanding as of now. I base this on the tests I ran, see question text and also from [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-)  in the "Method... not mocked" section.

It does seem that mock Android objects can be used as `ArgumentCaptor` types. These act more like "doubles", in that method verification is not performed on these default mock objects. I think this is true because [@durron597's `DummyTest` with the `TestSpannable` interface passed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055650/1768232)

Comment: The reason I add unitTest.returnDefaultValues = true to the project gradle.build file is because otherwise I get a 'not mocked' error.

Comment: One more note: verifying a method call with argumentCapture.capture() works when not using the Android api.